# conjugate of fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $\mathscr F$ be the Fourier transform. I am wondering if
$$
\overline{\mathscr F^{-1} \{e^{-i|\xi|^2} \mathscr F f }\}= \mathscr F^{-1} \{e^{+i|\xi|^2}\overline{ \mathscr F f}\}
$$

Comment: @flawr thanks then is this right? $\overline{\mathscr F^{-1} e^{-i|\xi|^2} \mathscr F f} = \mathscr F^{-1} \overline{e^{-i|\xi|^2} \mathscr F f(-\xi)} = \mathscr F^{-1} e^{i|\xi|^2 } \overline{\mathscr F f(-\xi)}$

Comment: I should assume $\xi$ is the frequency...

Comment: My impression is that we are being "passed along" a problem which is not well understood by the asker.  The evidence is the malleability of the problem's formulation and the lack of context.  What is the domain of $f$, so that we can better define the Fourier transform $\mathscr{F}$ and its inverse transformation.

Comment: @hyprfrco I rather suspect that $\xi$ is a vector, and that this might be a multidimensional FT. The original poster is regrettably terse. No context is given (happens for example when somebody copy/pastes a homework assignment here, and won't even try to explain their difficulties). Apparently to the point that voters disproved of the question and put it on hold for that reason. The question could be edited into shape, but only the original poster can tell use what those variables mean :-/

Comment: Correct as i fear 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
{\mathscr{F}^{-1}(x)\{F(\xi)\}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i2\pi \xi x}{F(\xi)}d\xi
$$

$$
\overline{\mathscr{F}^{-1}(x)\{F(\xi)\}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i2\pi \xi x}\overline{F(-\xi)}d\xi
$$

$$
\overline{\mathscr{F}^{-1}(x)\{e^{-i\xi^2}F(\xi)\}}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i2\pi \xi x}e^{i\xi^2}\overline{F(-\xi)}d\xi=\mathscr{F}^{-1}(x)\{e^{i\xi^2}\overline{F(-\xi)\}}
$$